# Having an issue with safari not displaying numbers in <a> tags

Tags: css, iphone, html, safari

I'm doing some browser testing with a responsive site, and ran into an issue with Safari that I cant track down the answer to. On the top of their page, they want a clickable phone number so that mobile devices and Skype users can easily call.

On every other browser it looks like it's supposed to:

[The Right Way!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1QbHvyOM3OCTzJydlNIMmNKTHc/view?usp=sharing)

In safari, however, I get this:

[The Wrong Way!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1QbHvyOM3OCOUFCcnhDX2ZlTFU/view?usp=sharing)

(rep is still too low to post pics, thus the Gdrive links)

What's going on here? Ive formatted the number portion to look as follows:

```
<h3 id="phone">Seattle <a id="ph-number" href="tel:2065272000">(206) 527-2000</a></h3>
```

The link works in every browser, it's just safari that's having issues with the display portion. Can anyone help me out with this (probably simple:) issue?

Comment: Hard to tell from just the HTML unfortunately. Any way to shine some light on CSS? What font family are you using (it may be missing glyphs somehow)? Double-check font-size?

Comment: That's the ticket, unsupported font-family. Thank you for jump starting my brain :) If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding as an answer for future searches:

Hard to tell from just the HTML unfortunately. Any way to shine some light on CSS? What font family are you using (it may be missing glyphs somehow)? Double-check font-size?

Comment: Likewise adding for future searches. That was the answer, Safari doesn't support some font-families that the others do. Check there if you haven't already!